# Canvas location properties not available/accessible within ItemsControl.DataTemplate

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp

I'm currently working on a project where I need to draw multiple shapes to a canvas. I've done this by using an ItemsControl, however the rectangles aren't drawn at their correct place. It looks like I do not have access to the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top properties at this stage... Anyone got a good alternative, workaround or solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{x:Bind Path=VML.Main.DrawableObjects}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas x:Name="content" Background="White" Canvas.ZIndex="2" Width="800" Height="600"></Canvas>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
            <vm:GalaxyTemplateSelector>
                <vm:GalaxyTemplateSelector.CelestialBodyTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="vm:CelestialBodyVM">
                        <Ellipse Height="{x:Bind Diameter}" Width="{x:Bind Diameter}" Fill="{x:Bind Colour}" Stroke="{x:Bind BorderColour}" StrokeThickness="1">
                            <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                                <TranslateTransform X="{x:Bind X}" Y="{x:Bind Y}"/>
                            </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                        </Ellipse>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </vm:GalaxyTemplateSelector.CelestialBodyTemplate>
                <vm:GalaxyTemplateSelector.LineTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="vm:LineVM">
                        <Line X1="{x:Bind X1}" Y1="{x:Bind Y1}" X2="{x:Bind X2}" Y2="{x:Bind Y2}" Stroke="{x:Bind Colour}" StrokeThickness="1"></Line>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </vm:GalaxyTemplateSelector.LineTemplate>
                <vm:GalaxyTemplateSelector.RectangleTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="vm:RectangleVM">
                        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="{x:Bind X}" Canvas.Top="{x:Bind Y}" Width="{x:Bind Width}" Height="{x:Bind Height}" Fill="Transparent" Stroke="{x:Bind Colour}" StrokeThickness="1"></Rectangle>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </vm:GalaxyTemplateSelector.RectangleTemplate>
            </vm:GalaxyTemplateSelector>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Does Ellipse and Line shape could draw correct ?

Comment: Yes, everything worked fine but when I tried to draw the square I couldn’t figure out how to draw it at its appropriate position

Comment: Could you share sample project, we could not make reproduce sample with above code, If you could share sample project, I will test base on that.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT This is the most basic version of the project;
https://github.com/tjeufoolen/FlatGalaxy-Canvas.Left-not-accessible
In this version you can see that when I try to render a rectangle in MainVM#UpdateView() at postion x, y it always ends up on 0,0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Canvas location properties not available/accessible within ItemsControl.DataTemplate

Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.canvas?view=winrt-19041) , if you have not placed `Rectangle` in the `Canvas` container, `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` will not effect. For this scenario, you could make Canvas container for `Rectangle`

```
<vm:GalaxyTemplateSelector.RectangleTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="vm:RectangleVM">
        <Canvas Height="600" Width="800">
            <Rectangle
                Canvas.Left="{x:Bind X}"
                Canvas.Top="{x:Bind Y}"
                Width="{x:Bind Width}"
                Height="{x:Bind Height}"
                Fill="Transparent"
                Stroke="{x:Bind Colour}"
                StrokeThickness="1" />
        </Canvas>
    </DataTemplate>
</vm:GalaxyTemplateSelector.RectangleTemplate>
```

Comment: Its seems that when I put the rectangles in their own canvas, the canvas position is off with the rest. https://prntscr.tjeufoolen.nl/1SB3T0UJpc.png Any way how to center this newly Canvas around its parent (ItemPanel)?

Comment: Please give the newly Canvas same size as parent  canvas.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference, sadly :(

Comment: I do not quite understand *the canvas position is off with the rest*，I checked your screenshot, but I can't catch some key information. And this is my [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAivK.png) and it looks correct

Comment: Ahh I see, It indeed looks good in the sample repo. I think its just some wrong code in my original project. Sorry for the trouble, I'll mark this answer as solved :)

Comment: Thanks, if you have any updates please post below or make new thread.